# iOSの実機でタップが拾えないのはなぜ？

Tags: ios, monaca, onsen-ui

Onsen UIを使って前後にページ遷移するアプリを作ってみました。

iPadとiPhoneのデバッガアプリで動作を確認したので、Apple Developerプログラムにも参加し、iOSアプリとしてビルドしたものの、実機にインストールすると動作しませんでした。デバッガー通りに動いてくれません。

具体的には最初の画面は表示されるものの、画面タップに対する処理が呼び出されないので、イベントが伝わってきていないように見えます。

また、最初の画面いっぱいに表示される画像を以下の処理でドラッグ禁止にしているものの、ドラッグに反応してしまいます。

```
ons.ready(function() {
  $(document).on('touchmove', 'img', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

何かビルド時に設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: monacaには明るくないのですが、「ビルドしたら」ではなく、「デバッガーでは動作していた挙動が実機では動作しないのはなぜか？」という質問意図に思えたので改題しました。問題があれば戻してください。

Comment: queseraさん、改題ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りです。ただし、拾いたいのはタップですが。touchmoveは拾えないでも構いません。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

ドキュメントを読み返して見たところ、FAQの5.16に解説がありました。ビルド前には手動でCordovaプラグインを指定する必要があるのですね。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/faq/application/

IDEでCordovaプラグインを取捨選択してみたら、必要なプラグインが解りました。